# twoside page number alignment on first page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, double-sided

I have a document which doesn't have the first page as "front", but rather the content follows immediately after `\maketitle`.

It starts with:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

I try to set up the header and footer:

```
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{titling}
\fancyhf[HC]{\thetitle}
\fancyhf[HL]{\theauthor}
\fancyhf[HR]{\today}
\fancyhf[FLO,FRE]{\thepage}
```

It works, but the number on the first page is centered, rather than aligned to right, as expected. Number on second page is aligned to right, and it should be on left. What's wrong?

---

Per request, here's the whole document (shortened)

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.3em}

\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{titling}
\fancyhf[HC]{\thetitle}
\fancyhf[HL]{\theauthor}
\fancyhf[HR]{\today}
\fancyhf[FRO,FLE]{\thepage}

\title{Title}
\author{Jonny Gangsta}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    Lorem ipsum blah blah... many paragraphs

\end{document}
```

Comment: the title page normaly does `\thispagestyle{plain}` so it has no header and centred number in the foot, you can redefine it to use a different style or redefine the plain style using fancyhdr.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to have any title page, it'll be printed with duplex and stapled in top left corner. Should I just set it to FC and not bother with left/right?

Comment: Not much more to show, I tried it and yes, `\maketitle` is causing the problems. Do you know how to stop `\maketitle` from messing up the footer alignment / mage numbering?

Comment: By title page I meant the page with the title. you have not shown any usable example so we have to guess, but I am guessing you have used `\maketitle`

Comment: I just used `\maketitle` and then follow the sections and paragraphs of text, on the same page.

Comment: As I said in the first comment use fancyhdr to redefine the plain page style, or just put `\thispagestyle{fancy}` after `\maketitle`

Comment: "not much more to show" every question should have a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ok, added the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\maketitle` sets `\thispagestyle{plain}` as you do not normally want the running head above the title. However you can use use fancyhdr to redefine the plain page style, or just put

```
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

after

```
\maketitle
```

To use the defined page style on the first page as well.